# IIS - Configuration file is not well-formed XML

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

```
<rule name="Posts2" enabled="true">
    <match url="^index.cfm\?section=latest.news&id=(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="post.php?id={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Problem is with the regex - any idea at all? I can't seem to work it out. I've run it on http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and it says

```
The reference to entity "id" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

When I change the ampersand to `&amp;` the rewrite doesn't seem to work on URLs such as `/index.cfm?section=latest.news&id=14726` despite it passing the test in IIS. Even when I escape the dots and question mark it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `{QUERY_STRING}` input using `conditions` perhaps:

```
<rule name="Posts2">  
  <match url="index\.cfm$" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="section=(latest\.news)" />  
      <add input="@{C:1}@_{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="@([^@]+)@_.*id=(\d+)" />  
    </conditions>  
   <action type="rewrite" url="post.php?id={C:2}" appendQueryString="false"/>  
 </rule>
```

URL's containing query strings are usually better handled this way, although if you really prefer not going this route then make sure you have the all the proper tags included, and also try escaping the `.` in between `latest\.news`.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Posts2">
      <match url="^index\.cfm\?section=latest\.news&id=(\d+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="post.php?id={R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I get the following: Configuration file is not well-formed XML. When I change the & to &amp; it doesn't seem to work (404 error) on the 2nd one but it does on the first :-)

Comment: Did you try using the first example with the <rewrite><rules> tags? It's unclear what you mean about the not well-formed XML. The second example likely will not work with the `&` included as it is. Maybe try using `index.cfm\?section=latest\.news.*id=(\d+)` instead on that one.

Comment: I spotted one other potential issue, change the url to `index\.cfm...` on the second one.